# How to set maximum amount of decimals in react

Tags: reactjs, decimal, limit

I created a calculator in react, but when I do some division where the result will be a repeating decimal, this result is exceeding the calculator display.

Example: 1 / 3 = 0.333333333333
[image: Calculator]

Could someone help me to make the result not pass the display?

I tried to use maxLength and toFixed methods, but neither worked

Here is my code:

```
export default function Calculator() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [oldnum, setOldNum] = useState(0);
  const [operator, setOperator] = useState();
  const [waitingForNumber, setWaitingForNumber] = useState(false);
  const [shouldClearNumber, setShouldClearNumber] = useState(false);

  function inputNum(event) {
    const input = event.target.value;
    const number = (Number(num) + Number(input))
    if (number > 999999999 && !waitingForNumber) {
      return;
    }

    if (waitingForNumber || num === 0 || shouldClearNumber) {
      setNum(input);
    } else {
      setNum(num + input);
    }
    setWaitingForNumber(false);
    setShouldClearNumber(false);
  }
  function calcular() {
    if (operator === "/") {
      setNum(parseFloat(oldnum) / parseFloat(num));
    }
    if (operator === "X") {
      setNum(parseFloat(oldnum) * parseFloat(num));
    }
    if (operator === "-") {
      setNum(parseFloat(oldnum) - parseFloat(num));
    }
    if (operator === "+") {
      setNum(parseFloat(oldnum) + parseFloat(num));
    }
    setShouldClearNumber(true);
    console.log("calculou!!!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852366/how-to-make-textinput-only-accept-up-to-2-decimal-places-with-a-max-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer isn't a good general solution, it doesn't limit the number of decimal points, it just cuts off characters that may or may not be after the decimal.

The correct answer is using `toFixed`, like Mel Carlo Iguis's answer. You could call `toFixed` everytime before setting state:

```js
setNum(Number(newValue.toFixed(1))) // 1 for 1 decimal place, adjust as needed
```

Although that method loses information-- if you want to keep `num` high-precision for future calculations, you can instead just use `toFixed` during the actual render step. **This is the pattern I'd recommend**:

```js
<div> {num.toFixed(1)} </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try using  `setState(Number(state).toFixed(1))`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Answer (score -1):

You could convert the number to a string, then use slice() to trim down the number to a specified amount of digits.
And convert it back to a number for your purposes.

For example if you wanted to keep 7 digits, you could do

```
num.toString();
num.slice(0, 6);
Number(num)
```

Comment: Note that this will slice of characters from the entire number, not just after the decimal point. It could turn  4005.00 to, for example, 400, if you took a slice of (0,3).